# How to fix 'NoReverseMatch at /' error on Django app?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to just build a basic application to work off in the future. I keep getting an error saying  "NoReverseMatch at/ Reverse for 'about' not found. 'about' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

I've searched for other people with the same issue and it seems their issues used an older version of Django and they used different functions from what I'm using.

I'm using a book called Hello Web App by Tracy Osborn, which simplifies everything, and all the code I've found dealing with a similar problem seems far more complicated than what I've done so far. I've tried changing my views.py file to request the base.html file instead of the index.html file which didn't work. I've double checked my syntax on all files, including the html file. And, I've made sure the urls.py file matched up exactly. I still keep getting the same error.

here is my urls.py file

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from condata import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about/',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'),
        name='about'),
    path('contact/',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'),
        name='contact'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

base.html

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      {% block title %}
        Project
      {% endblock title %}
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
    {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    {% block footer %}{% endblock footer %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm really just expecting a basic page with a few links to go the html pages I've written for about and contact. It seems very basic, I just don't have a lot of experience with this and I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong. I really appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I actually shut down the server and just restarted it and its working. I think the files may have just not been uploading/saving properly as I was doing it all simultaneously.

Comment: Please post full stack trace error.